# Execute program from another directory using Runtime.exec()

Tags: java, ffmpeg, runtime, exec

I want to execute a program (`System.getenv("appdata") + "ffmpeg"`). I also want to be able get a process or something that could get me the consle output. I have tried "cmd /C " + `System.getenv("appdata") + "ffmpeg"` before and it didn't seem to work. Any help is appreciated!

Here is some code:

```
Process p = exec(testFFMpeg);
    int ex = -1;
    try {
        ex = p.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        CrashHandler.reportCrash("FFMpeg", "Unable to test FFMpeg", "start up with more permissions");
    }

    if(ex == 0){
        System.out.println("Normal execution, exit value: " + ex);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;

        do{
            try {
                line = br.readLine();
                System.out.println(line);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                CrashHandler.reportCrash("FFMpeg", "Unable to test FFMpeg", "start up with more permissions");
            }
        }while(line != null);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Execution exit value: " + ex);
    }
}

private static Process exec(String[] cmd){
    try {
        return Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        CrashHandler.reportCrash("FFMpeg", "Unable to test FFMpeg", "start up with more permissions");
    }
```

The exact location of the file is: `System.getenv("appdata") + "\VinVid\" + "ffmpeg.exe".

Comment: Please look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Comment: One thing is that how would I get the output instead of saving to a file.

Comment: What output you talking about?

Comment: I mean the consle log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The output was going to the error stream, not the inputStream.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing path separator, try this

```
System.getenv("appdata") + "\\ffmpeg"
```

Comment: can you tell us what error you are getting? Did you add the extension `.exe` to ffmpeg?

Comment: I tried Aneesh's answer but added p.waitFor(); right after creating the BufferedReader and it simply says nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In your code change this line `line = br.readLine();` to    `line += br.readLine();`
This is how you run a windows process in java.
I don't know what output you want. If your asking to print the output of the process you ran, this code helps :

```
String line;
String pidInfo ="";

Process p =Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getenv("appdata") +"ffmpeg.exe");

BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    pidInfo+=line; 
}

input.close();

System.out.println(pidInfo);
```

Comment: There is simply no output

Comment: Maybe your process doesn't give any outputs. Replace your `cmd` with this `System.getenv("windir") +"\\system32\\"+"tasklist.exe"` and try to see if any output comes

Comment: it just stops the app and says nothing same with `System.getenv("windir") +"\\system32\\"+"cmd.exe"` If I run ffmpeg from cmd it throws out a bunch of output

Comment: I'll try using apache commons exec